# Is it possible to create an executable file from a docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, executable

I have a docker image that I would like to compile into some form of executable file, is this something that is possible?

I'm a noob to docker, go easy on me.

edit - I'm using the term executable lightly here. I'm realizing that docker is not the solution and will probably need to start looking into web assembly.

Comment: Not really, no; usually you'd put an executable file into a Docker image and not _vice versa_.  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I have a docker image that has all the dependancies installed to run a cli application. I've gotten this into a repo on docker hub and can use it as a base image, I would like to run this in the browser on a per user basis instead of on the server so the user is using their cpu for processes.

Comment: I posted elsewhere and was told that if I can get an executable that the browser can download then this might be doable.

Comment: you're looking for an executable file that the user has to download. This would be entirely different from a container that's running as an executable. in this case, docker is not the answer.

Comment: If it needs to run in the browser, you'll have to rebuild it using browser-native technology (most likely Javascript or a derivative; if you're brave, WebAssembly).  You can't run Docker images in a browser, and you _definitely_ can't run arbitrary executables there – that'd be a massive security nightmare.

Comment: The more I talk to people about this the more I'm hearing about WebAssembly. I've used it before but simply for packaging web apps and that was more of "Here's this things that has web assembly, have fun"

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In your Dockerfile, if you add ENTRYPOINT and your command, it'll treat the image as an executable, once it's built.

So if you have ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "hello world"] for example, when you run a container based off this image, the it'll use that command as its execution point.

Comment: Yes I've been thinking this, I can use `docker exec <image> <command>` but I need to figure out how to run this in the clients browser. I want to use the users cpu on a per user basis instead of the servers cpu.

Comment: @bryanstevens314 You can't run a docker image in a browser.

Comment: I'm slowly realizing this. I know what I want to accomplish is doable though, maybe just not with docker